# DTPicker change event

Tags: vba, datepicker

I'm using Office 2007.  I have a UserForm with multiple fields, including two date fields, one formatted for Date (DTPicker1) and the other formatted for Time (DTPicker2).  They've been working well for years.
I recently added a new event: DTPicker1_Change.
All the code works as expected, as long as I stay in the same month.  However, Once I click on the down arrow for the displayed date I receive the month picker.  When I click on the right arrow to change the month, something unexpected happens.  I get a few seconds delay, thrown into Debug, and the DatePicker UI seems to have jumped ahead about a year.  I'm thrown into Debug because there is no corresponding data for a date that far in advance.  From Debug, I can go back to the UI, change to the date I need (next month), go back to Debug, and move the cursor to restart the DTPicker1_Change event.  After that, things behave as expected.
I tried to rename the event to DTPicker1_Exit, but I get a compile error message: "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name".
Why does changing the month with a DTPicker_Change event cause this problem?  Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed the event to DTPicker1_CloseUp and then everything worked as desired.  Changing to the next month and selecting a new date works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes so work it:

```
Private Sub DTPicker1_CloseUp()
    Call Sub
End Sub
```